# Regular expression for float

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am checking flaot value using this regular expression

```
var re = /^\d{1,5}\.\d{1}$/;
```

But it currently checks value which have only decimal and not allowing interger, can i modify this expression tho accept both integer and float

Currently accepting 100.0
I want to enter both 100 and 100.0 so that i want to change thisregular expression

Some input wilbe a valuable for me

Comment: I guess you've to provide a condition such if (str.maches("regex")) || str.matches("anotherRegex"))

Comment: Can Same expression use for both interger and float

Comment: I guess no but I am not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `/^\d{1,5}(\.\d{1})?$/;`